# Different session variables between Domain and Subdomain

Tags: php, apache, subdomain

Is it possible to setup your two different project on a same domain and same server but different SESSION variables and point to different folders?

One is on maindomain.com (share session variables with subdomains except dashboard.maindomain.com) and one is 'dashboard.maindomain.com'

This implies that session variables must be shared between the primary domain and any subdomain, except dashboard.

Comment: Probably best to simply use a different session _name_ for the dashboard subdomain then. You _could_ try and limit the visibility of the session cookie as well, but that is going to be a bit more complex in this scenario, I think. (And you might want to configure different storage directories for the session files.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

In theory, it should be as easy as just properly configuring different cookie domains, as well as having separate storage (e.g. different file directories, in case you're using file-based sessions).

However, because cookies for `example.com` would be valid for and sent by clients to all subdomains, make sure to use a different session cookie name for your `dashboard.` subdomain. That way, it won't attempt to process cookies that weren't intended for it.
In addition, that's a security concern because your `dashboard.` app will now effectively be able to sniff cookies that are only intended for your main domain and other subdomains.

So, while technically possible, it might not be a good idea to do that.